# Getting the "facebook code" to obtain long-lived-access-token from server side. Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to follow this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) to get a long-lived user token. (see "Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens")

The diagram is quite explicit, and I thought it should be easy.

But the problem comes when I try to get the "code."

As you can see, this should be the request:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/client_code?access_token=...&amp;client_secret=...&amp;redirect_uri=...&amp;client_id=...`

But the problem is that since I'm on the Server side, I'm not able to redirect the user since that's a client work. (Isn't it?)

So, since I got this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 191,
    "fbtrace_id": "EqPakhHX9i6"
  }
}
```

I tried this:

`&amp;redirect_uri=https://www.google.com/&amp;` (to see if it eats that URI)

But no chance.

I was looking for similar questions, but people use to use the client side, and I don't have any access to the Client. Actually, the client is waiting for this `code` from me, as the diagram shows.

So, I don't have any idea how I can do it.

Maybe someone here had the same problem.

Comment: So you are referring to the section “Generating Long-Lived User Tokens from Server-Side Long-Lived Tokens”? (That is the only one on that page where a `code` parameter comes into play.) That describes the process to create long-lived tokens to be used _on the client side_. So if you have no client side, then it makes no sense that you would implement that flow in the first place.

Comment: ok, cool, is there a way to do it on the server side? And if that's on the client side, why it says "from Server-Side" ? This is the first time that I'm using Facebook in an App. Maybe it's a stupid question, but I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: You need to have the short-lived user access token first. And getting one of those always means going through the login flow first, and that has to happen on the client (i.e., in the user’s browser.) There is no way to log a user in server-side only.

Comment: Yeah, I already did it. And when I get the token, can I (do I need) get the long lived user token? (Thanks for your answers :) )

Comment: The flow to exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived one is the first one described on that page, and doesn’t involve an additional `code` parameter - you just make the one server-side API call, and get the long-lived token in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use the next url with cURL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={client-id}&client_secret={secret-id}&fb_exchange_token={short-token}
```